# SFTP chrooted to home directory and users wanted to have a write permission to home directory

Tags: chroot, sftp

I have a new request from the user and these are the following requirements

1. Request to have an `sftp` user account and disable shell access
2. Sftp User should only see their home directory (ie..  `/home/user1`) and should not able to see other home directory
3. Sftp user should able to write directly inside the `/home/user1`

As I see most of the forums you can write only by adding additional folder like `/home/user1/upload`.

Here are my configurations below, I'm using RedHat 6.5 with `openssh-server-5.3p1-112.el6_7.x86_64` version.

- `/home` directory is currently set as `root:root`
- `/home/user1` currently set as `root:root`
- contents of `/etc/passwd`

  ```
  $ cat /etc/passwd
  user1:x:806:806::/home/user1:/sbin/nologin
  cat /etc/group
  sftponly:x:2002:user1
  ```
- contents of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

  ```
  $ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u 0022

  Match group sftponly
      ChrootDirectory %h
      ForceCommand internal-sftp
      X11Forwarding no
      AllowTcpForwarding no
  ```
- contents of `/home`

  ```
  $ ls -la /home
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 29 10:23 user1
  ```

With this permission and configuration above `sftp` is working fine but I could not meet the requirement of the user because he needs to upload a folder directly in his `/home/user1` directory

I've also tried to set an ACL:

```
    $ setfacl -m user:user1:rwx /home/user1
    $ getfacl /home/user1

    # file: user1/
    # owner: root
    # group: root
    user::rwx
    user:user1:rwx
    group::r-x
    mask::rwx
    other::r-x

    $ sudo service sshd restart
```

I expect that I can able to write already but it failed to connect using winscp or filezilla it saying Network error software caused connection about, Authentication failed.

When I look the sshd logs:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/secure
fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/home/user1"
```

This means setting the ACL can cause an issue.

Comment: You have to make sure the home directory of the user is owned by the user itself, and no other write permissions are there except for the user. `chown <user> <homedir>; chmod go-w <homedir>`

Comment: Im trying but still getting bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/home/user1" which mean if we point the sftp chroot  to home directory it needs to be root:root permission

Comment: That will not work. Openssh does not allow you to set the ownership of the user's home directory to root:root, because it considers this setup to be insecure (you may persuade the writers of Openssh that this is not so, or you may change the source and recompile it).